# When using OPENROWSET, how can I filter out non-numeric rows of a specific column?

Tags: sql-server, csv, t-sql, openrowset

I'm using `OPENROWSET` to import regular csv data files into a SQL table. Very occasionally one of the columns (which is supposed to be a `SMALLINT`) contains the value 'UNKNOWN', which obviously causes an error.

Assume that I cannot change the schema of our tables, and cannot stop the 'UNKNOWN' value from appearing in the files. How can I filter these rows out in the `OPENROWSET` query? I have tried inserting `MAXERRORS=1000` but the file still errors.

Comment: What's wrong with `WHERE YourIntColumn <> 'UNKNOWN'` in the `WHERE` (with additional handling of `NULL`s if needed)?

Comment: @Larnu seems it was a case of me overthinking it. Thanks. I am off to get coffee now.

Comment: Or, alternatively, a `CASE` expression in the `SELECT`: `CASE YourIntColumn WHEN 'UNKNOWN' THEN NULL ELSE YourIntColumn END` and then you `INSERT` *all* the rows and use `NULL` for `'UNKNOWN'` (as `NULL` does represent an unknown value after all).